# UIPopoverPresentationController can not be dismissed on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uipopovercontroller

I'm implementing a CABTMIDICentralViewController (Apple's pre-fab BTLE MIDI configuration panel). The code below is Apple's sample code - unmodified.

It works perfectly on iPad, but on iPhone/iPod it results in an uncloseable fullscreen view. The code clearly creates a Done button, but it isn't shown on the devices.

The common answer is "you need a UINavigationController", but there is one being made in this code. So I'm not sure what else is missing?

```
- (void)doneAction:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)configureCentral:(id)sender
{
    CABTMIDICentralViewController *viewController [CABTMIDICentralViewController new];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    // this will present a view controller as a popover in iPad and modal VC on iPhone
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                      target:self
                                                      action:@selector(doneAction:)];

    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popC = navController.popoverPresentationController;
    popC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    popC.sourceRect = [sender frame];

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    popC.sourceView = button.superview;

    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` to view popovers in iPhones. By default it will be presented in the style of an already presented view controller.

Add this piece of code to present the controller as popover

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller traitCollection:(nonnull UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```